# Hide title bar in pantheon-terminal?

Tags: pantheon-terminal, user-interface

The title bar (that above the tabs) is hidden when pantheon-terminal is full-screen.

How can this bar be hidden when not full-screen? Alternatively, I'd be happier if I could make both it and the tab bar half the height that they presently occupy, but this doesn't seem to be an option in dconf.

Comment: title bar of any application is hidden when in full-screen (F11). that has nothing to do with what you ask

Comment: @cipricus it aids in explaining what I would like

Comment: I think it would be better to mention the behavior of other terminal emulators that have this option, if any. Also: http://askubuntu.com/a/277963/47206

Comment: just like `gnome-terminal`, `pantheon-terminal` doesn't have a setting for that, unlike `xfce4-terminal` ([here](http://superuser.com/a/750876/162573)) or `terminator` ([here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/terminator-on-start-title-bar-how-to-disable-4175473921/#post5012105)).  In `dconf-editor` under `org.pantheon.terminal.settings` I see nothing on this.

Comment: I'm almost certain there is not a way do this in `pantheon-terminal` and there will probably never be a way to do it. It goes against the design principles of elementary.

Comment: what if we don't use tabs, because of `screen` or `tmux`? there should be at least an option to hide this.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to remove the titlebar when Terminal is windowed.